# Is there a function to load a non-atomic value atomically?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdatomic

In C++20 we can write:

```
double x;

double x_value = std::atomic_ref(x).load();
```

Is there a function with the same effect?

I have tried `std::atomic_load` but there seem to be no overloads for non-atomic objects.

Comment: Non-portably of course, there is GNU C `__atomic_load_n(&x, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html.  Are you looking for a function that takes a `double*`? I doubt you'll find one in ISO C++20, but IDK if there is one that takes a `std::atomic_ref<double> *` or reference.

Comment: @PeterCordes One taking a `double*` or `double&`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your comment in fact answer my question. If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-portably of course, there is GNU C `__atomic_load_n(&x, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` [`__atomic` builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).

I'm pretty sure you don't find a function in ISO C++ that takes a `double *` or `double &`.

Possibly one that takes a `std::atomic_ref<double> *` or reference, I didn't check, but I think the intent of `atomic_ref` is to be constructed on the fly for free inside a function that needs it.

If you want such a function, write you own that constructs + uses an `atomic_ref`.  It will all inline down to an `__atomic_load_n` on compilers where `atomic` uses that under the hood anyway.

---

But do make sure to declare your global like this, [to make sure it's safe + efficient to use with `atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref/required_alignment).  It's UB (I think) to take an atomic_ref to an object that's not sufficiently aligned, so the `atomic_ref` constructor can simply assume that the object you use is aligned the same as `atomic<T>` needs to be.

```
alignas (std::atomic_ref<double>::required_alignment)  double x;
```

In practice that's only going to be a problem for 8-byte primitive types like `double` inside structs on 32-bit targets, but something like `struct { char c[8]; }` could in practice be not naturally aligned if you don't ask for alignment.